# not (not false) = True?

Tags: python, boolean

I'm currently on page Conditionals & Control Flow, Python, Code Academy.

I've made this thinking it will be False but it is wrong.

**Make me false!**

```
bool_three = not (not False) == True
```

Objects in parentheses are worked out first, so by my logic:

```
not (not False [which becomes True]) = True

not True [which is false] = True
```

Comment: What coding language is this? How are you testing it?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? not operation comes first, followed by == operation and followed by =. so bool_three = false == true, definitely it is false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> not (not False [which becomes True]) = True

What makes you think "not not false" would be true?  If a boolean value is negated, it becomes the opposite value.  If it's negated *again*, it becomes the original value.

Let's derive it a step at a time...

1. not (not False) == True
2. not (True) == True
3. False == True
4. False

Answer (score 4):

bool_three = not (not False) == True

Here that's goes :

**not ( not False )** become **not ( true )** became **false**.

Then False == True (which is false)

so then **bool_three = false**

Answer (score 3):

Quick Python interpreter check:

```
>>> not not False == True
False
```

Comment: I got the same result in Python 2.7