# What's happening with the order of operations comparing "x is not y" vs "x is (not y)" in Python?

Tags: python

What's happening in Python to make the following different?

```py
>>> one = 1
>>> one is not False
True
>>> one is (not False)
False
```

Thinking of `not` as simply negating what comes after it, I would've thought they'd both have the same output as the second. What's happening to make them different? What are the "order of operations" of the first example?

Comment: Try `1 is True` and see what you get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [not (not false) = True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803777/not-not-false-true)

Comment: These aren't the same comparisons... `one is (not False)` is the same as `one is True`. If you want to negate `one is True`, you'd write `not (one is True)`, which is the same as `one is not True`

Comment: @ahmed That's not really the same thing. That question is about multiple negations; this one hinges on `is not x` working differently than `is (not x)`.

Comment: I assume there has to be a dupe of this, but I can't find it yet. This is close/related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485180/python-is-not-operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ast` module to see how Python parses the two differently.

In the first case, the parser recognizes `is not` as a single (two-word) operator, with operands `one` and `False`.

```
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse("one is not False"), indent=4))
Module(
    body=[
        Expr(
            value=Compare(
                left=Name(id='one', ctx=Load()),
                ops=[
                    IsNot()],
                comparators=[
                    Constant(value=False)]))],
    type_ignores=[])
```

In the second case, the parser recognizes `is` as a single (one-word) operator, with operands `one` and `not False`.

```
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse("one is (not False)"), indent=4))
Module(
    body=[
        Expr(
            value=Compare(
                left=Name(id='one', ctx=Load()),
                ops=[
                    Is()],
                comparators=[
                    UnaryOp(
                        op=Not(),
                        operand=Constant(value=False))]))],
    type_ignores=[])
```

Answer (score 3):

The first instance asks if `one` is not False which it is because "one" is 1 so the result is True. Here, the `is not` acts as its own operator.

The second instance asks if `one` is `(not False)` which is the same as asking if `one is True`, but `one` is not True it is 1. Here, the `not` is modifying the `False` to make it `True`

Keep in mind that `is` is not the same as `==`.

For example `1 == True` is True, but `1 is True` is False.

Comment: "not is modifying the is " No, `is not` is *it's own operator*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I guess one could argue that at some ("parser"?) level, the `not` does modify the `is`. For example [this grammar excerpt](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) says `"is" ["not"]`, making it look like an `is` with an optional `not` modifier. And I wouldn't be surprised if the parsing were implemented like that, i.e., first recognizing the `is` and then "switching" to `is not` when it sees the `not`.

Comment: That might be misleading. The [full grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), for instance, has `isnot_bitwise_or` and `is_bitwise_or` as two separate non-terminals, one consisting of the tokens `'is'` and `'not`, the other having only `'is'`, without implying any kind of modifier relationship between the two. `is not` could just as well have been spelled `aint` as far as the parser is concerned.